# Syntax for checking value of radio button

Tags: javascript, radio-button

Iḿ trying to check for a value of a radio input with Javascript, here is an if statements in one the functions in my code:

```
 if (understanding1.value == yes ){
  document.getElementById("result1Y").innerHTML = 
  document.getElementById('name1').value;
}
```

I'm having trouble with the syntax of the if (understanding1.value == yes ) do ...

Here is what my code is suppose to do:

The user inputs some text > the text has the id = "name1"
The user selects one of the following options > yes; kind of; no The user clicks enter button >
The function organizeUnderstanding1() is suppose to organize the input name1 into either result1H; result1M; result1E; depending on what they selected with the radio inputs

Here is the full version of my code:

```html
 <div>
        <input type="text" id="name1">
    </div>

 <div id="understandingCheck1">
        <p>Question 1?</p>
        <input type="radio" id="yes1" name="understanding1" value="yes" required>
        <label for="yes">yes</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="kindOf1" name="understanding1" value="kindOf">
        <label for="kinda">kind of</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="no1" name="understanding1" value="no">
        <label for="no">no</label><br><br>
        <button onclick="hideUnderstandingCheckDiv(); organizeUnderstanding1();">Enter</button>
    </div>
    
      <div id="workDiv">
        <p>Here´s what you said YES to:</p>
        <p><span id="result1H"></span></p>
        <p>Here's what you said KIND OF to:</p>
        <p><span id="result1K"></p>  
        <p>Hereś what you said NO to:</p>
        <p><span id="result1Y"></span></p>
      </div>
    
    
      <script>
     
      
      
      function organizeUnderstanding1() {
     var understanding1 = document.querySelector('input[name = "understanding1"]:checked').value;
              if (understanding1.value == yes ){
                 document.getElementById("result1Y").innerHTML =                        document.getElementById('name1').value;
              } else if (understanding1.value == kinda ){
                document.getElementById("result1K").innerHTML =                         document.getElementById('name1').value;
              } else if (understanding1.value == no ){
                document.getElementById("result1N").innerHTML =                         document.getElementById('name1').value;
              } else {
                break;
              }
       }
       
    
   
      </script>
```

Comment: You need quotes: `== 'yes'`

Comment: With these kinds of questions it's often useful to include an error message and/or unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're checking for variables which you never assigned instead of strings. You need to wrap quotes around each value you want to check the string equality.

```html
 <div>
        <input type="text" id="name1">
    </div>

 <div id="understandingCheck1">
        <p>Question 1?</p>
        <input type="radio" id="yes1" name="understanding1" value="yes" required>
        <label for="yes">yes</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="kindOf1" name="understanding1" value="kindOf">
        <label for="kinda">kind of</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="no1" name="understanding1" value="no">
        <label for="no">no</label><br><br>
        <button onclick=organizeUnderstanding1()>Enter</button>
    </div>
    
      <div id="workDiv">
        <p>Here´s what you said YES to:</p>
        <p><span id="result1Y"></span></p>
        <p>Here's what you said KIND OF to:</p>
        <p><span id="result1K"></p>  
        <p>Hereś what you said NO to:</p>
        <p><span id="result1N"></span></p>
      </div>
    
    
      <script>
     
      
      
      function organizeUnderstanding1() {
     var understanding1 = document.querySelector('input[name = "understanding1"]:checked').value;
              if (understanding1== 'yes' ){
                 document.getElementById("result1Y").innerHTML =                        document.getElementById('name1').value;
              } else if (understanding1 == 'kinda' ){
                document.getElementById("result1K").innerHTML =                         document.getElementById('name1').value;
              } else if (understanding1== 'no' ){
                document.getElementById("result1N").innerHTML =                         document.getElementById('name1').value;
              } else {
                break;
              }
       }
       
    
   
      </script>
```

Comment: it still doesn't work, i used your feed back to update the code here is a link to a try it editor, but no error is display when I run it, nothing happens at all, do you know why that is?  here is the link to the w3schools try it editor:  https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GK4S00OT9NX8

Comment: Also: Thank you for the helping me!

Comment: @hp672 Just tested your editor and it was due to the way we checked for the value. The variable `understanding1` already checks for the `.value` so when we check if it equals 'yes' or 'no' we do not need to check `understanding1.value` instead we only need to check for `understanding1`. Another error was you had the result search for `result1H` instead of `result1N`. Updated my answer hope that helps!

Comment: @hp672 here's a working demo on w3schools. I removed the kinda to make it easier to read and understand: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GK5PS82XFMKP

Answer (score 0):

```js
 //you select all radio input 
     var selectedRadioVal;
     var radio1 = document.querySelector("#yes1")
     var radio2 = document.querySelector("#no1")
    
      //when radio1 is clicked
     radio1.onclick = function(){
     radio2.checked=false
     selectedRadioVal =radio1.value
     }
      //when radio2 is clicked
      radio2.onclick = function(){
     radio1.checked=false
     selectedRadioVal =radio2.value
     }
      //after clicking enter
      function organizeUnderstanding1() {
      //get text input value (name)
    let inputname = document.getElementById('name1').value;
     
              if (selectedRadioVal == 'yes' ){
                 document.querySelector("#result1Y").innerHTML =   inputname                     
                 selectedRadioVal=""
              }  if (selectedRadioVal == 'no' ){
                document.querySelector("#result1H").innerHTML =  inputname
                selectedRadioVal=""
              } else {
               // return;
              }
       }
```

```html
<div>
        <input type="text" id="name1">
    </div>

    <div id="understandingCheck1">
        <p>Question 1?</p>
        <input type="radio" id="yes1" class="understanding1" value="yes" >
        <label for="yes">yes</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="no1" class="understanding1" value="no">
        <label for="no">no</label><br><br>
        <button onclick=organizeUnderstanding1()>Enter</button>
    </div>
    
      <div id="workDiv">
        <p>Here´s what you said YES to:</p>
        <p id="result1Y"></p>
        <p>Hereś what you said NO to:</p>
        <p id="result1H"></p>
      </div>
```

Comment: This answer has a bug: you need to include the `name` attribute on each `<input type="radio">`; otherwise the user can select both of them at the same time.

Comment: I know, but I was hesitant to add the code because the details of the problem were missing. I mentioned this before."also you use document.querySelectorAll('.understanding1')..checked = false with for loop for deselect radio button" So you must add "understanding1[i].checked=false" in for loop before onclick function

Comment: I wrote it more simply for clarification. I updated the code try now

Comment: What? We have a proper way of doing this: the `name` attribute. The `name` attribute there already in the question. You removed it. Why? Why? Why? It will always work, even if scripts are disabled or have errors. Why are you trying to use your own script instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your question starts with this code block:

```
 if (understanding1.value == yes ){
  document.getElementById("result1Y").innerHTML = 
  document.getElementById('name1').value;
}
```

This is trying to compare the value of `understanding1.value` with the value of a *variable* called `yes`. What you want to do is compare the value of `understanding1.value` with the *string* `'yes'`, so you need to add quotes around it:

```
 if (understanding1.value == 'yes'){
  ...
}
```

I think this answers your question. But there are a few other things that you should change:

1. Fix some other bugs in your code (use `understanding1` instead of `understanding1.value` and use the correct span IDs (`result1H`, `result1K` and `result1Y` instead of `result1Y`, `result1K` and `result1N`, respectively).
2. Use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of `innerValue`. Otherwise, the value will be interpreted as HTML (that’s why the name `innerHTML` contains “HTML”). With your code, if the user enters `<script>doSomethingEvil();</script>` into the textbox and clicks the button, then it will execute the function `doSomethingEvil()`.
3. Get rid of that `else`/`break` bit – it doesn’t actually do anything.
4. Convert all those `if` and `else if` statements into a `switch` statement.
5. Make your code easier to read by fixing the indenting and other spacing.
6. Check whether the user actually entered valid input before doing anything else. I say this because of this line: `<button onclick="hideUnderstandingCheckDiv(); organizeUnderstanding1();">Enter</button>` which is, apparently, supposed to hide all the inputs as soon as the user clicks the button. Since it’s not clear how the page is supposed to work overall, I have not done this part.

Complete code:

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" id="name1">
</div>

<div id="understandingCheck1">
    <p>Question 1?</p>
    <input type="radio" id="yes1" name="understanding1" value="yes" required>
    <label for="yes">yes</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="kindOf1" name="understanding1" value="kindOf">
    <label for="kinda">kind of</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="no1" name="understanding1" value="no">
    <label for="no">no</label><br><br>
    <button onclick="hideUnderstandingCheckDiv(); organizeUnderstanding1();">Enter</button>
</div>

<div id="workDiv">
    <p>Here´s what you said YES to:</p>
    <p><span id="result1H"></span></p>
    <p>Here's what you said KIND OF to:</p>
    <p><span id="result1K"></p>  
    <p>Hereś what you said NO to:</p>
    <p><span id="result1Y"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
    function organizeUnderstanding1() {
        var understanding1 = document.querySelector('input[name = "understanding1"]:checked').value;
        
        switch (understanding1.value {
            case 'yes':
                document.getElementById("result1H").textContent = document.getElementById('name1').value;
                break;
            case 'kinda':
                document.getElementById("result1K").textContent = document.getElementById('name1').value;
                break;
            case 'no':
                document.getElementById("result1Y").textContent = document.getElementById('name1').value;
                break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

I just have to say this: I am shocked that no one else commented on the use of `innerHTML`. This seems like the kind of beginner trap – and serious security vulnerability – that experienced developers *need* to comment on every time they see it.